# Active Directory improve performance in C# - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, performance, active-directory

Is it possible to improve response time of the following function with the help of multi-threading (`Task.Run` etc) or any other good technique?

```
UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>();

public void FillUserList(string machineName, string groupName)
{
    UserCollection.Clear();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
        return;

    var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, groupName);

    var members = group.GetMembers();

    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        var user = new User { DisplayName = member.Name, UserId = member.SamAccountName };
        UserCollection.Add(user);                
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing slowness? What is your current experience with respect to performance for this method?

Comment: Yes,performance is getting worse with the increase in the number of users in the group. If any group have 2 users(5 secs) 7 users (12-14 secs) to respond back!

Comment: the code looks pretty straight forward the only thing I can think of is network issues being the latency issue or after you assign members variable try setting the machineContext = null also inside your method put the `UserCollection` object unless you are not showing the full scope of that object I can't tell without knowing how often FillUserList is being called..

Comment: Basically, I have created WPF application having two textboxes. User is providing machinename and groupname. After groupname is entered, with the help of expander I am displaying users(two labels) associated with the respective group below every group. This function is used very often.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noticed, the code is very straightforward and does not really have any potential to run in multiple threads (if I'm mistaken, please let me know). While it probably is possible to slightly improve the response time of your method, unfortunately I don't think it will ever be blazing fast.

Sometimes things just like to take their sweet time and as developers we just have to accept it and trick users into thinking that they are not waiting at all.

**So, here's comes my advice:**

You are running this method (`FillUserList`) synchronously in the same thread that you use to process events and do everything else GUI-related (UI thread). This makes the application "freeze" while your method is busy loading users. Usually, when you cannot avoid longer loading times, you redirect the heavy task to the background (background thread, or even the same thread, but you run it asynchronously) while keeping the UI fully responsive.

I prepared a sample solution using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) closely resembling your current scenario. The only difference is that I'm using a console application, and not WPF. However, you should be able to easily modify my code to work in your scenario.

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> UserCollection = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FillUserList("Hello", "World");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void FillUserList(string machineName, string groupName)
    {
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        var temporaryUserCollection = new List<string>();

        worker.DoWork += (s, ea) => { YourLongRunningTask(machineName, groupName, temporaryUserCollection); };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) => { UserCollection = temporaryUserCollection; Console.WriteLine("Loaded."); };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        // I'm writing to the console, but you should show
        // some sort of loading indicator (spinner, "please wait" dialog, progress bar, etc.) in this line
        Console.WriteLine("Loading...");
    }

    public static void YourLongRunningTask(string machineName, string groupName, List<string> userCollection)
    {
        // Paste your current FillUserList code here
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        userCollection.Add("A");
        userCollection.Add("B");
        userCollection.Add("C");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to dispose the group and machine context as shown below,

```
   group.Dispose(); 
   machineContext.Dispose();
```

It might help in improving the performance.

**Code:**

```
    UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public void FillUserList(string machineName,string groupName)
    {
        UserCollection.Clear();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
            return;

        var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
        var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, groupName);

        var members = group.GetMembers();

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            var user = new User { DisplayName = member.Name, UserId = member.SamAccountName };
            UserCollection.Add(user);                
        }

       //try disposing the objects
       group.Dispose(); 
       machineContext.Dispose(); 
    }
```

**Note:** You can also use using statement instead of .dispose. See the code below,

```
    UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public void FillUserList(string machineName,string groupName)
    {
        UserCollection.Clear();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
            return;

        using(var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, machineName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate)){

          var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, groupName);

          var members = group.GetMembers();

          foreach (var member in members)
          {
             var user = new User { DisplayName = member.Name, UserId = member.SamAccountName };
             UserCollection.Add(user);                
          }

         //try disposing the objects
         group.Dispose(); 
       }
    }
```